# div height 100% inside another div

Tags: css, html

How do I set div height to 100% if the div is inside other div's. I get 0px height of that div.
Here is my code (div #aaa should be 100% of white space without scrollbar):

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="aditional_menu"></div>
            <div id="aaa"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="sub_footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uUEwg/859/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a height of the outer div, or put some content into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a `DIV` height to a `pct` that will cover the page. What you're trying to do would require `JS` or a JavaScript library like `jQuery` to calculate the screen size and adjust the `div` accordingly. Alternatively you can set a `min-height` in `px` and fill the `div` with content.

Here's a link to a CSS hack that may work for you: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/min-height/